# How can I copy labels from one node to another?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm looking for any way to copy labels from one node to another. I found this post [How can we copy labels from one node to another in one cypher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35191765/how-can-we-copy-labels-from-one-node-to-another-in-one-cypher) . But it looks like auther asked about simple way to do it. And i'm looking for any solution like iterating through label list. I tried this

```
Create (q:Label1:G2:Label2{id: 14111, t: 99999999999999})-
[r1:CONSISTS_OF{t:99999999999999}]->
(g1:Label1:G1:Label2:Label3{t: 99999999999999, name:'name1'}),
(q)-[r221:CONSISTS_OF{t:99999999999999}]->
(g2:Label1:G1:Label2:Label4{t: 99999999999999, name:'name2'}),
(q)-[r2:CONSISTS_OF{t_end:99999999999999}]->
(g2123:Label1:G1:Label2:Label3{t_end: 99999999999999, name_ru:'name2'})
return *

Match (g2:G2)-->(g1:G1) with g1 
Create (g1Instance) set g1Instance = g1 
FOREACH (n IN labels(g1) | set g1Instance: n) return g1Instance
```

But instead of labels (g1) it sets label "n" to g1Instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously said [@cybersam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35192141/4989460):

> Unfortunately, labels currently cannot be set directly from data
>   values.

But you can use apoc procedure [`addLabels`](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures#creating-data):

```
MERGE (T:TestLabel) WITH T
CALL apoc.create.addLabels( [ id(T) ], ['Label1','Label2'] ) YIELD node
RETURN node
```